# Simplifying the calling signature for repeatedly used arguments

Tags: python, signature

I have a bunch of functions with similar inputs. This means that there is a list of standard arguments that are repeatedly there, and some may vary:

```
def f1(arg, std_arg1, std_arg2, ...):
    # do something

def f2(another_arg, std_arg1, std_arg2, ...):
    # do something else
```

I now would like to simplify the calling signature by having a list or dictionary containing all the parameters. This way it's easier to call all the different functions and also to write new functions. This problem is getting worse by the fact that the functions may call other functions from other modules/files with a signature containing again many of these arguments like:

```
def super_f(arg1, arg2, std_arg1, std_arg2, ...):
    # depending on some args call eventually
    f3(arg2, std_arg1, std_arg2, ...)
```

,where `f3` again calls something with e.g. `arg2` and `std_arg2`
I want to tidy up the code and the question is now what's the cleanest way to go for here.
Ideally I would like to have something like:

```
def super_f(all_the_args):
   # depending on some args call eventually
   f3(all_the_args)
```

where `f3` again calls something with `all_the_args`. Or at least with some of the arguments packed. Although this might not read well or be inefficient (I don't know).

My ideas were:

1. Collect some or all arguments in a list and 'unpack' them in the function:

```
std_args = [std_arg1, std_arg2, std_arg3, ...] # or potentially all the args
def f(arg, std_args):
    std_arg1, std_arg2, ... = std_args
    # do something
```

2. Collect them in a dictionary like:

```
std_args = {"std_arg1": std_val1, "std_arg2": std_val2, ...}
def f1(arg, std_args):
    # rewrite "std_arg1" -> std_args["std_arg1"]
```

3. Put all the arguments on the global scope, such there are known to every function, which sounds dirty to me and I have to do it in every module/file.
4. Use a class with list or dict as input for the constructor, where all the parameters are stored and then known on that scope.

```
def class func(object):
    def __init__(self, std_args):
        self.std_arg1 = std_args[0]
        self.std_arg2 = std_args[1]
        ...
    
    def f1(self, arg):
        # do something with arg, std_arg1, std_arg2, ...
```

This might be the cleanest solution, but needs some rewriting (ok, potentially just some find->replace) and there is a lot of *ulgy* `self.` in my code.

For option 1, 2, 3 I think I have to do this on every 'level' of the calling structure. It might be possible with option 4 to do it more easily throughout the 'levels'/files.

Is there a better solution to this problem? Or are there any suggestions how to write this code in a better structure?

Comment: Are you familiar with *args and **kwargs dict?

Comment: A bit. I think I this way I can solve 'one way', by defining `def f(*args): ...`, but I still have to write it out when calling the function (as far as I know) with : `f(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)` instead of `f(*args)`. And then still the name of the variable itself is unknown to the function, such that I can't use it with e.g. 'x = arg1 * 5'. This might be solved to some extension with using a dict in `**kwargs`

Comment: I've had to write lots of code like this, and I tend to use `**kwargs`.  Each of the arguments has a specific name, and I have freedom to add arguments or modify arguments within each function without needing to know about all the other arguments.